# Having trouble adding information from a database into a table via connection string

Tags: c#, sql, visual-studio-2012, connection-string

This is kind of a vague question, but I'm not totally sure where to start.  I've tried to look through resources online and I can't really find anything.

I'm making an MVC web application in Visual Studio (C#) and I have tables on my HTML pages that I would like to populate from a table in a database in SQL Server.  (It's password protected but I have access to it).

Anyways, I've been using this to try and connect to the database from my Web.config:

```
<connectionStrings>
<add name="UATConnectionString" connectionString="Data Source=***.***.***.**;Initial    Catalog=********;User ID=******;Password=******* />
</connectionStrings>
```

However, once I have that, I'm not sure how I can actually populate my tables with the data from the database.  I've tried looking up some stuff online but none of it is working for me.  :(

I appreciate any and all help.  If you could explain things in as simple as terms as possible I would appreciate it, as I am still familiarizing myself with coding in general.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
public System.Data.Common.DbProviderFactory GetFactory()
        {
            System.Data.Common.DbProviderFactory providerFactory = null;
            providerFactory = System.Data.Common.DbProviderFactories.GetFactory("System.Data.SqlClient");
            return providerFactory;
        } // End Function GetFactory


protected System.Data.Common.DbProviderFactory m_providerFactory = null;
m_providerFactory = GetFactory();



    public System.Data.IDbConnection GetConnection(string strDb)
    {
        System.Data.Common.DbConnection con = m_providerFactory.CreateConnection ();
        con.ConnectionString = GetConnectionString (strDb);

        return con;
    }




        public  System.Data.DataTable GetDataTable(System.Data.IDbCommand cmd, string strDb)
        {
            System.Data.DataTable dt = new System.Data.DataTable();

            using (System.Data.IDbConnection idbc = GetConnection(strDb))
            {

                lock (idbc)
                {

                    lock (cmd)
                    {

                        try
                        {
                            cmd.Connection = idbc;

                            using (System.Data.Common.DbDataAdapter daQueryTable = this.m_providerFactory.CreateDataAdapter())
                            {
                                daQueryTable.SelectCommand = (System.Data.Common.DbCommand)cmd;
                                daQueryTable.Fill(dt);
                            } // End Using daQueryTable


                            /*
                            using (System.Data.SqlClient.SqlDataAdapter daQueryTable = new System.Data.SqlClient.SqlDataAdapter((System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand)cmd))
                            {
                                daQueryTable.Fill(dt);
                            } // End Using daQueryTable
                            */
                        } // End Try
                        catch (System.Data.Common.DbException ex)
                        {
                            //COR.Debug.MsgBox("Exception executing ExecuteInTransaction: " + ex.Message);
                            Log("cMS_SQL.GetDataTable(System.Data.IDbCommand cmd)", ex, cmd.CommandText);
                            throw;
                        }// End Catch
                        finally
                        {
                            if (idbc.State != System.Data.ConnectionState.Closed)
                                idbc.Close();
                        } // End Finally

                    } // End lock cmd

                } // End lock idbc

            } // End Using idbc

            return dt;
        } // End Function GetDataTable
```

Then you can Create a command like this:

```
    public System.Data.IDbCommand CreateCommand(string strSQL)
    {
        System.Data.IDbCommand idbc = this.m_providerFactory.CreateCommand();
        // idbc.CommandText = string.Format(strSQL, " /* TOP 1 */ ", "OFFSET 0 FETCH NEXT 1 ROWS ONLY");
        idbc.CommandText = strSQL;

        idbc.CommandTimeout = 300;

        return idbc;
    } // End Function CreateCommand
```

And use it like this:

```
System.Data.DataTable dt = null;

using(System.Data.IDbCommand cmd = CreateCommand("SELECT * FROM YOUR_Table"))
{
      dt = GetDataTable(cmd);
}
```

And you can still add this function:

```
    public System.Data.DataTable GetDataTable(string strSQL, string strInitialCatalog)
    {
        System.Data.DataTable dt = null;

        using (System.Data.IDbCommand cmd = this.CreateCommand(strSQL))
        {
            dt = GetDataTable(cmd); //, strInitialCatalog);
        } // End Using cmd

        return dt;
    } // End Function GetDataTable
```

The you can do:

```
System.Data.DataTable dt = GetDataTable("SELECT * FROM YOUR_Table");
```

To get the connectionstring from the web/app .config, you can use this function:

```
    public static string GetConnectionString()
    {
        return GetConnectionString(null);
    } // End Function GetConnectionString


    protected static string strStaticConnectionString = null;
    public static string GetConnectionString(string strIntitialCatalog)
    {
        string strReturnValue = null;
        string strProviderName = null;


        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(strStaticConnectionString))
        {
            string strConnectionStringName = System.Environment.MachineName;

            if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(strConnectionStringName))
            {
                strConnectionStringName = "LocalSqlServer";
            }

            System.Configuration.ConnectionStringSettingsCollection settings = System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings;
            if ((settings != null))
            {
                foreach (System.Configuration.ConnectionStringSettings cs in settings)
                {
                    if (StringComparer.OrdinalIgnoreCase.Equals(cs.Name, strConnectionStringName))
                    {
                        strReturnValue = cs.ConnectionString;
                        strProviderName = cs.ProviderName;
                        break; // TODO: might not be correct. Was : Exit For
                    }
                }
            }

            if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(strReturnValue))
            {
                strConnectionStringName = "server";

                System.Configuration.ConnectionStringSettings conString = System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings[strConnectionStringName];

                if (conString != null)
                {
                    strReturnValue = conString.ConnectionString;
                }
            }

            if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(strReturnValue))
            {
                throw new ArgumentNullException("ConnectionString \"" + strConnectionStringName + "\" in file web.config.");
            }

            settings = null;
            strConnectionStringName = null;
        }
        else
        {
            if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(strIntitialCatalog))
            {
                return strStaticConnectionString;
            }

            strReturnValue = strStaticConnectionString;
        }

        InitFactory(strProviderName);
        System.Data.Common.DbConnectionStringBuilder sb = GetConnectionStringBuilder(strReturnValue);


        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(strStaticConnectionString))
        {
            if (!Convert.ToBoolean(sb["Integrated Security"]))
            {
                sb["Password"] = DES.DeCrypt(System.Convert.ToString(sb["Password"]));
            }
            strReturnValue = sb.ConnectionString;
            strStaticConnectionString = strReturnValue;
        }


        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(strIntitialCatalog))
        {
            sb["Database"] = strIntitialCatalog;
        }


        strReturnValue = sb.ConnectionString;
        sb = null;

        return strReturnValue;
    } // End Function GetConnectionString
```

Which requires:

```
    public static System.Data.Common.DbConnectionStringBuilder GetConnectionStringBuilder(string strConnectionString)
    {
        System.Data.Common.DbConnectionStringBuilder dbConString = m_ProviderFactory.CreateConnectionStringBuilder();
        dbConString.ConnectionString = strConnectionString;

        return dbConString;
    } // End Functin GetConnectionStringBuilder
```

This will get the connection-string with name Environment.MachineName, or else the connection string named "server:

```
<connectionStrings>
<add name="YOUR_DEV_MACHINE_NAME" connectionString="Data Source=***.***.***.**;Initial    Catalog=********;User ID=******;Password=******* />


<add name="server" connectionString="Data Source=***.***.***.**;Initial    Catalog=********;User ID=******;Password=******* />

</connectionStrings>
```

And that's how you do it properly.
As always, it's a lot easier to do it improperly:

```
    public static System.Data.DataTable LazyGetDataTable()
    {
        System.Data.DataTable dt = new System.Data.DataTable();
        dt.TableName = "lalala - Not really necessary";

        using (System.Data.SqlClient.SqlDataAdapter da = new System.Data.SqlClient.SqlDataAdapter("SELECT * FROM YOUR_TABLE", "YOUR CONNECTION STRING HERE"))
        {
            da.Fill(dt);
        }

        return dt;
    } // End Function LazyGetDataTable
```

But if you do it that way, you will have to rewrite your code if you ever want to change from Microsoft SQL-Server to something else.

Answer (score 0):

There are many ways to achieve this.
You can use entity-framework:

[Entity Framework](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/ee712907.aspx)

or DataAdapters:

[SqlDataADapters](http://www.dotnetperls.com/sqldataadapter)

(The 2nd Link has a small example code)